# SpringBoot + Zuul + Oauth2 - OAuth2TokenRelayFilter Reauthorization

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-oauth2

I am upgrading a group of Spring Boot / OAuth2 / Zuul applications from Spring Boot 1.3.8.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Brixton.SR6 to Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Dalston.SR1.  As a result of the upgrade, my applications stopped working.  Upon further review, I discovered that my SSO client was attempting to reauthorize whenever it tried to relay a request through Zuul.  Digging deeper the cause of my issues was in the changes made to OAuth2TokenRelayFilter.  Code was added to send a 401 error if a token was unable to authorize, however from my looking at it, this also ignores the fact that a token may have already been retrieved and user already authorized

To get my applications running, I had to disable the OAuth2TokenRelayFilter by adding the following to the applications.properties.

```
zuul.OAuth2TokenRelayFilter.pre.disable=true
```

I then made a small modification to OAuth2TokenRelayFilter and saved it as MyOAuth2TokenRelayFilter.  I simply added the following to the getAccessToken method.

```
String value = (String) ctx.get(ACCESS_TOKEN);
if ( value != null && !value.isEmpty()){
            return value ;
        }
```

Full Code (again simply modified from the original).

```
public class MyOAuth2TokenRelayFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
    private static final String TOKEN_TYPE = "TOKEN_TYPE";
    private Map<String, Route> routes = new HashMap<String, Route>();

    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    public MyOAuth2TokenRelayFilter(ProxyAuthenticationProperties properties) {
        this.routes = properties.getRoutes();
    }

    public void setRestTemplate(OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth instanceof OAuth2Authentication) {
            Object details = auth.getDetails();
            if (details instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
                OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauth = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) details;
                RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
                if (ctx.containsKey("proxy")) {
                    String id = (String) ctx.get("proxy");
                    if (routes.containsKey(id)) {
                        if (!Route.Scheme.OAUTH2.matches(routes.get(id).getScheme())) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ctx.set(ACCESS_TOKEN, oauth.getTokenValue());
                ctx.set(TOKEN_TYPE, oauth.getTokenType()==null ? "Bearer" : oauth.getTokenType());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("authorization", ctx.get(TOKEN_TYPE) + " " + getAccessToken(ctx));
        return null;
    }

    private String getAccessToken(RequestContext ctx) {
        String value = (String) ctx.get(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        if ( value != null && !value.isEmpty()){
            return value ;
        }
        if (restTemplate != null) {
            // In case it needs to be refreshed
            OAuth2Authentication auth = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder
                    .getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (restTemplate.getResource().getClientId()
                    .equals(auth.getOAuth2Request().getClientId())) {
                try {
                    value = restTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // Quite possibly a UserRedirectRequiredException, but the caller
                    // probably doesn't know how to handle it, otherwise they wouldn't be
                    // using this filter, so we rethrow as an authentication exception
                    ctx.set("error.status_code", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Cannot obtain valid access token");
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

With my applications most all users are validated prior to making a zuul route call, so I don’t know if this breaks anything in the event a route call is made and a token has not yet been retrieved.

Is this a viable solution or am I missing something and just masking a greater problem?